# How to override (monkeypatch) the document and element specific `querySelector` implementations and how to restore each original functionality again?

Tags: javascript, monkeypatching, queryselector, defineproperty, propertydescriptor

I have a local testing environment, where I want to temporary override querySelector. I know that monkeypatching is bad practice, but in this case this code will only be used locally on developer side. I have this snippet that I wrote (overrides querySelector to fetch all selectors with another substring in the selector called addonID):

```
  function maybeOverrideForTestStart(partialIDOfWidget, fullIDOfWidget) {
    if(!isLocal) return;
    const addonID = fullIDOfWidget.replace(partialIDOfWidget, "");
    Element.prototype.querySelectorTemp = Element.prototype.querySelector.bind(Element);
    
    Element.prototype.querySelector = function(selector) {
      const element = this.querySelectorTemp(selector);
      if (element) return element;
      if (addonID) {
        return this.querySelectorTemp(selector + addonID) || null;
      }
    };

  }
  function maybeOverrideForTestEnd() {
    if(!isLocal) return;
    Element.prototype.querySelector = Element.querySelectorTemp;
  }
```

I call `maybeOverrideForTestStart` in the beginning of my testing, and `maybeOverrideForTestEnd` in the end. But this doesn't work, and I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm getting either `someElement.querySelector is not a function` or `"Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"`.

Note - I also cannot understand if this also overrides the document.querySelector and document.body.querySelector or just someElement.querySelector.

Help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `Element.prototype.querySelector.bind(Element)` should be `Element.prototype.querySelector`.

Comment: Also, this only changes `someElement.querySelector` (incl. `document.body.querySelector`) because `document` is not an instance of `Element`, it's an instance of `Document`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the naming of `maybeOverrideForTestStart` to `patchQuerySelectors` since its implementation changes as well.

In order to correctly redefine/patch the modified `querySelector` implementations (one needs to do it for both `Document.prototype` and `Element.prototype`) and also to exactly restore each default state, one should choose an approach which makes use of each prototypal `querySelector`'s [*property descriptor*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor). The function does patch each modified version but also does return a function which restores each original setting, everything via [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

```js
// apply the monkey patch.
const restoreDefaults = patchQuerySelectors(true, 'bar_123', 'foo');

console.log(
  'after patching ... ', {
  restoreDefaults,
  elementQuery: Element.prototype.querySelector,
  documentQuery: Document.prototype.querySelector,
});

// use the patched/modified versions of `querySelector`
console.log(
  "document.querySelector('body') ...",
  document.querySelector('body'),
);
console.log(
  "document.body.querySelector('script') ...",
  document.body.querySelector('script'),
);

// restore each specific `querySelector` to its correct default.
restoreDefaults();

console.log(
  'after restoring ... ', {
  elementQuery: Element.prototype.querySelector,
  documentQuery: Document.prototype.querySelector,
});

// use the restored versions of `querySelector`
console.log(
  "document.querySelector('body') ...",
  document.querySelector('body'),
);
console.log(
  "document.body.querySelector('script') ...",
  document.body.querySelector('script'),
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
// get the monkey patching right.

function patchQuerySelectors(isLocal, partialIDOfWidget, fullIDOfWidget) {
  if (!isLocal) return;

  const addonID = fullIDOfWidget.replace(partialIDOfWidget, "");
  const {
    // the original/native implementation.
    value: elementQuery,
    // the original descriptor of the native implementation.
    ...elementConfig
  } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, 'querySelector');

  const {
    value: documentQuery,
    ...documentConfig
  } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, 'querySelector');

  // the modified element specific `querySelector` implementation.
  function modifiedElementQuery(selector) {

    // apply the correct context to the original version.
    const element = elementQuery.call(this, selector);

    if (element) {
      return element;
    }
    if (addonID) {
    // apply the correct context to the original version.
      return elementQuery.call(this, selector + addonID);
    }
  };
  // the modified document specific `querySelector` implementation.
  function modifiedDocumentQuery(selector) {
    const element = documentQuery.call(this, selector);

    if (element) {
      return element;
    }
    if (addonID) {
      return documentQuery.call(this, selector + addonID);
    }
  };

  // - redefine the properties via the default descriptors
  //   and the newly assigned modified functions.
  Object
    .defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'querySelector', {
      value: modifiedElementQuery,
      ...elementConfig
    });
  Object
    .defineProperty(Document.prototype, 'querySelector', {
      value: modifiedDocumentQuery,
      ...documentConfig
    });

  function restoreDefaults() {
    // - redefine/restore the properties via the default descriptors
    //   and the locally stored original `querySelector` implementations.
    Object
      .defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'querySelector', {
        value: elementQuery,
        ...elementConfig,
      });
    Object
      .defineProperty(Document.prototype, 'querySelector', {
        value: documentQuery,
        ...documentConfig,
      });
  }
  return restoreDefaults;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have an issue with `querySelector.call`, you forgot to give a `this` argument.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you need to `.bind()` the function, but you could keep a reference to the original function in a constant, for example

```js
const querySelector = Element.prototype.querySelector;

function maybeOverrideForTestStart(partialIDOfWidget, fullIDOfWidget) {
  // ....

  Element.prototype.querySelector = function (selector) {
    const element = querySelector(selector);
    if (element) return element;
    if (addonID) {
      return querySelectorTemp(selector + addonID) || null;
    }
  };
}

function maybeOverrideForTestEnd() {
  // ...
  Element.prototype.querySelector = querySelector;
}
```

Comment: `querySelector(selector + addonID)` can't work because you lost the `this` binding. Use `.call(this, ...)`.